# Facebook meta tags issue - debugger says not in the <head> tags

Tags: facebook, tags, meta

I have an issue with facebook, longer period of time the meta tags are not working on my website. The title is showing perfectly on facebook, however the image doesn't. Also, when I go through fb debugger, it says: Your page has meta tags in the body instead of the head. This may be because your HTML was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree.
Please fix this in order for the tags to be usable.

My website is: http://www.popularno.mk/, but this error message also comes up at every single post (example: http://www.popularno.mk/2013/07/27/vozila-grcija/)

I'd be very grateful for a solution.

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Byte-Order Mark that seems to be messing things up for the debugger.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html><body>
<p>&#65279;
```

You may want to deal with removing that from your code before proceeding further.

Comment: That just happened to me. Usefull BOM comment.